# Is Azure good for hosting a beginner Silverlight project?

Tags: .net, asp.net, silverlight, azure

I want to learn a bit of Silverlight by writing a simple proof-of-concept RIA. I am looking for hosting that is free and has minimal IT/configuration concerns. I see that Azure has a [free introductory special](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/offers/popup.aspx?lang=en&locale=en-US&offer=MS-AZR-0001P). Is it advisable to go with Azure, or is there another, simpler offering out there?

(I have intermediate web dev experience (Django) and intermediate C# experience, although I haven't used ASP.NET before. I have an MSDN subscription and have access to Visual Studio, Expression Studio, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any kind of hosting will work for a Silverlight application as long as you can serve html and reference your ClientBin.

Answer (score 0):

First of all where are you located? I live in Lithuania and nearest Azure servers are in USA and there be some in Europe later, but I heard rumors from Lithuanian MS that there won't be servers here for at least another 3+ years.